# make a flutter project taking a long time in vs code and android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-web

recently I uninstalled all my android studio setup and then install the new version of android studio, but I face some problems when create the first project. it needs to take a loooong time and won't start. I have already tried all options such as making a project in CMD, vs code, and android studio but the result is the same, it won't start.
anyone can help me with this problem, please?

Comment: Depends on your internet connection as first runs are always downloading required  'stuff'

Answer (score 0):

Try

flutter clean

then load packages and run